# Responsive design for display:none

Tags: javascript, html, css

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, I cant work it out.

I have a list of information contained within seperate div

On page load only the title of each div is showing.

```
<div class='listing' >    

<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('interactive');">
   <h3 class='title'>Title</h3>
</a>

    <div id="interactive" style="display:none;">
      <div class="web"><p><a href="#">#</a></p></div>
      <div class="phone"><p><a href="Tel:#">Tel: #</a></p></div>
      <div class="email"><p><a href="#">#</a></p></div>
      <p>copy: ipsum blah </p>
      <p>Blah Blah</p>
    </div>
```

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

onclick toggles the visibility of the content. So far so good.

Say now I start to add some simple responsive design. If on small screen I want one column of div, no problem. If slightly wider I make a media query to adjust the width of the div accordingly.

Say I have 2 columns. If I onclick to toggle visibility it of course still shows the content in the 4 column responsive layout. But I want the unhidden content to now revert to full width (might be lot of content, and looks strange to extend down only half a column).  So essentially I need the onclick toggle visibility div to always be full screen width.

Can I do this in css? I've tried styling the 'revealed' div but no joy.

Any pointers would be most welcome???!!!! Im sure its easy but Ive tried everything and Im still learning all this!

Comment: Are you using any css frameworks or just html and css. Add code in jsFiddle.

Comment: @Harsh Adding code _in SO snippet_ please.

Comment: Please add the complete code including css styles

Comment: @harsh all I have so far is styling on the .listing div. Here is for 2 column layout. How to get onclick to go to 1 column?! Thaknks                                 .listing {
 border: 1px solid #009999;
 color: #fff;
 background-color:#009999;
 text-align: center;
 width: 45%;
 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
 
}'

Comment: @davidreeves where are the media queries?

Comment: @harsh this would be an example of a media query, to reduce the width. So the width of div is 45%, and stays at 45% if I onclick toggle visibility. How to make this 45% revert back to 100% on click is my question??! Sorry if im not clear. I tried styling the div 'interactive' to be 100% but doesnt effect it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend avoiding using JavaScript to change style directly whenever possible.  Classes are better for this, and they let you do things like customize the styling via media queries, as well as animating content changes.

First, change your HTML to use a class rather than a hard style:

```
<div id="interactive" class="listing-item">
```

Next, change your JS to toggle the class, rather than change the style directly:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
  // Note: classList is IE10+, so you might have to do more work
  // to support older browsers
   e.classList.toggle('visible');
}
```

Finally, use CSS to handle the magic:

```
.listing-item {
    display: none;
}
.listing-item.visible {
    display: block;
}

@media (...) {
    .listing-item.visible {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you want to get fancy, try some CSS3 styling:

```
.listing-item {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.listing-item.visible {
    // pick something reasonable here, to make sure your
    // content is visible.  Too high, and the animation will be off.
    max-height: 999px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind instruction. I have tried your code, and it works just how my own attempt worked. But I have the same issue. If div class=listing is at 45% width, .listing-item.visible is still at 45% when I click on it. I want it to revert to 100% width upon becoming visible!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ox4Lts2c/ Layout is here. This is design for use on mobile/tablet. Say we are on landscape. 2 columns is perfect for the title. But on click it should revert to full width, regardless of width of visible div. Currently, the .visible will extend all the way down the left of the screen. Not even sure it is possible!

Comment: So, you want the outer div to expand when an inner item is visible, or you want the inner div to expand outside the parent container?

Comment: Note: both are possible, but require different approaches.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I want the inner div to expand onclick outside its parent, to full width. Ive had some joy incorperating something like this http://jsfiddle.net/J3FTN/

Comment: It's a lot harder to expand only the inner child outside the parent's container, but if you can focus on newer browsers, you can set the child's width to `100vw` when it's expanded.  A `vw` is 1% of the browser's width, so `100vw` means `100%` of the browser's width.  You'll also need to make sure that you are using `box-sizing: border-box` (which you should be using anyway).